# Failed to compile: module not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong but i keep getting this message:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'components/List' in 'C:\Users\kobby\Documents\Lambda-School\buildwene\src\coek\hn-clone\src\components\App'
```

This is what the import looks like in App/index.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import List from 'components/List';
import { colorsDark } from 'styles/palette';
```

My folder dir is like so: 
`C:\Users\kobby\Documents\Lambda-School\buildweek\hn-clone\src\components\App\index.js`

This is the path for List:
`C:\Users\kobby\Documents\Lambda-School\buildweek\hn-clone\src\components\List`

Comment: look like you dont have @alias setup in your project.. If this project is just for education purpose, I think in your `App/index.js`, your path to List component should be `import List from '../List/index'`

Comment: try ```import List from '../List';```

Answer (score 0):

Path should be like this: `import List from '../List/index';`